# How can I send text from an text_field into an URL parameter in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby/Rails and I'm trying to create a basic website.

I want to have a text_field that lets the user type in a message. Then, the user can click a submit button. I want to url to be something like:

```
.../foo?message="Whatever the user typed in"
```

Currently I have `<%= link_to "Submit", foo_path(:message => "hello") %>`. This works in getting the parameter to be "hello", but how can use the text from the text_field instead?

I'm confused because text_field requires object_name and method parameters but I don't need either an object or a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need form with textfield and `get method`

```
<%= form_tag ..... , :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag %>
<% end %>
```

just like google

```
<form id="gbqf" name="gbqf" method="get" action="/search"  class="gbes">
  <input type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" name="q" id="gbqfq">
</form>
```